# How to View or Open List Created in AutoHosted App?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, autohosted

I am trying to create AutoHosted app, in that I have created Custom list in my VS project.

After this I published the app and uploaded the App file to the O365 app catalog. But I am not able to open my list which I have created in my project.

I am trying to open list using this URL:

```
https://someguid.o365apps.net/Lists/mylist/AllItems.aspx
```

Any suggestions?

How can I view the list?

> Update:

I have found way to open the list:

If you want to open the list which you have created it in visual studio the URL will be as follows:

```
https://maindomain/appName/Lists/ListName/AllItems.aspx
```

But I still don't know that what I should type in my code. Because I can't have static URL in my code, in that I have used :

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlUnit" runat="server" NavigateUrl="/Lists/MyList">MyList</asp:HyperLink>
```

It redirects the URL which I have mentioned above. So any idea for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the list as follows.

```
https://main-domainname/sites/site-where-app-is-installed/nameofapp/Lists/list-name/AllItems.aspx
```

The above link will of course depend on where you have installed your app but you should be able to work it out and it will be different for everyone.

To link to the list from your page depends on the setup of your project in VS, for instance I have all my pages in a folder called pages and all my lists in a folder called lists. So my URL's will look like this.

```
<a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="../Lists/cboDepartmentList">Manage Departments</a>
```

Where my VS structure looks like this.

[image]

S

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work.

Comment: I found that from way.

Comment: +1 is for because of your answer I am able to find the way to open the list.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: But I am talking about AutoHosted app.. This you are showing is SharePoint hosted app structure. In That we can add list as an WebPart page control on aspx page.

Comment: sorry not fully understanding your question...if you add a webpart you need to tell the webpart where the list is?